# A little question about dim and rank

Tags: linear-algebra

Is $\dim(\ker(A-I))$ equal to $\text{rank}(A)-\text{rank}(A-I)$?

I mean does $$\dim(\ker(A-I))=\text{rank}(A)-\text{rank}(A-I)$$

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by $A-I$? Maybe you should tell more about your specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that $A$ is a square matrix and $I$ is the identity martix.

Let $A=O$.

Then $\dim(ker(A-I))=0$, but $rank(A)-rank(A-I)=-rank(-I) \ne 0$